# Dynamically getting height of UILabel according to Text return different Value for iOS 7.0 and iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I am using the this method for getting the height of the UILabel Dynamically:

```
+(CGSize) GetSizeOfLabelForGivenText:(UILabel*)label Font:(UIFont*)fontForLabel Size:  (CGSize)LabelSize{
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:fontForLabel constrainedToSize:LabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    return (labelSize);
}
```

With this solution I am getting the exact size of UILabel if my code is running on below iOS 8 
but if I run my application on iOS7 then it is returns a different value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to dynamically set the frame, like below:

> Tested on iOS 6 to iOS 12.2

**Swift:**

```
let constrainedSize = CGSize(width: self.titleLable.frame.size.width, height:9999)

let attributesDictionary = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 11.0)]

let string = NSAttributedString.init(string: "textToShow", attributes: attributesDictionary as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])

var requiredHeight = string.boundingRect(with: constrainedSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)


if (requiredHeight.size.width > self.titleLable.frame.size.width) {
    requiredHeight = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.titleLable.frame.size.width, height: requiredHeight.size.height)
}
var newFrame = self.titleLable.frame
newFrame.size.height = requiredHeight.size.height
self.titleLable.frame = newFrame
```

**Objective C:**

```
CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(self.resizableLable.frame.size.width  , 9999);

NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:11.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                      nil];

NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"textToShow" attributes:attributesDictionary];

CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

if (requiredHeight.size.width > self.resizableLable.frame.size.width) {
    requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,0, self.resizableLable.frame.size.width, requiredHeight.size.height);
}
CGRect newFrame = self.resizableLable.frame;
newFrame.size.height = requiredHeight.size.height;
self.resizableLable.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: I am also doing the same but the frame(here as you have newFrame) value are different for iOS6.1 and iOS7

Comment: I have try with this too [other code I have tried](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7) but the result is same…..

Comment: Where exactly are you using `maximumLabelSize` ? This doesn't work.

Comment: Good solution. Also easy to implement.

Comment: Condition should be
if (requiredHeight.size.height > self.certificateNameLabel.frame.size.height)

Comment: swift version please

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz: you could have updated, but thanks I updated now.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a total solution for width and height. Put these in your AppDelegate:

```
+(void)fixHeightOfThisLabel:(UILabel *)aLabel
{
    aLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aLabel.frame.origin.x,
                              aLabel.frame.origin.y,
                              aLabel.frame.size.width,
                              [AppDelegate heightOfTextForString:aLabel.text
                                                         andFont:aLabel.font
                                                         maxSize:CGSizeMake(aLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)]);
}

+(CGFloat)heightOfTextForString:(NSString *)aString andFont:(UIFont *)aFont maxSize:(CGSize)aSize
{
    // iOS7
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        CGSize sizeOfText = [aString boundingRectWithSize: aSize
                                                  options: (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                               attributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:aFont
                                                                                       forKey:NSFontAttributeName]
                                                  context: nil].size;

        return ceilf(sizeOfText.height);
    }

    // iOS6
    CGSize textSize = [aString sizeWithFont:aFont
                          constrainedToSize:aSize
                              lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return ceilf(textSize.height;
}

+(void)fixWidthOfThisLabel:(UILabel *)aLabel
{
    aLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aLabel.frame.origin.x,
                              aLabel.frame.origin.y,
                                [AppDelegate widthOfTextForString:aLabel.text
                                                          andFont:aLabel.font
                                                          maxSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, aLabel.frame.size.height)],
                              aLabel.frame.size.height);
}

+(CGFloat)widthOfTextForString:(NSString *)aString andFont:(UIFont *)aFont maxSize:(CGSize)aSize
{
    // iOS7
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        CGSize sizeOfText = [aString boundingRectWithSize: aSize
                                                  options: (NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                               attributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:aFont
                                                                                       forKey:NSFontAttributeName]
                                                  context: nil].size;

        return ceilf(sizeOfText.width);
    }

    // iOS6
    CGSize textSize = [aString sizeWithFont:aFont
                          constrainedToSize:aSize
                              lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return ceilf(textSize.width);
}
```

then to use this, set the label's text:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.text = @"Everyone loves Stack OverFlow";
```

and call:

```
[AppDelegate fixHeightOfThisLabel:label];
```

Note: label's numberOfLines has to be set to 0.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using any of the system fonts, they changed in iOS 7 so they would be different sizes.

---

Also, `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` is deprecated in iOS 7. Use [sizeWithAttributes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes%3a) instead (if you are on iOS 7)

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer didn't satisfy me so I had to dig this up in my code:

```
CGSize possibleSize = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10] //font you are using
                          constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(skillsMessage.frame.size.width,9999)
                              lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
newFrame.size.height = possibleSize.height;
label.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: sizeWithFont is deprecated in iOS7.

Comment: Use
        CGSize boundingBox = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:.....

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is too long. You can use the following:

```
+(CGSize) GetSizeOfLabelForGivenText:(UILabel*)label Font:(UIFont*)fontForLabel Size:  (CGSize) constraintSize{
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    CGRect labelRect = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:fontForLabel} context:nil];
    return (labelRect.size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever height I am getting via this code(method I have written in this question above).Its provide the height in float value **(86.4)** , once we get that and try to set that height to UILabel, but we need to get the value from the height with ceil **(87)** instead of the value as it is **(86.4)**. I have resolved my problem with this approach. And thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up finally and hope this will help you. I checked iOS version as Apple itself doing in the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1), which involves checking the Foundation Framework version and used #pragma to suppress the Deprecated: warning raising by iOS 7 or later with "- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size".

```
+ (CGSize)getStringBoundingSize:(NSString*)string forWidth:(CGFloat)width withFont:(UIFont*)font{

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        // for iOS 6.1 or earlier
        // temporarily suppress the warning and then turn it back on
        // since sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: deprecated on iOS 7 or later
        #pragma clang diagnostic push
        #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
            maxSize = [string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maxSize];
        #pragma clang diagnostic pop

    } else {
        // for iOS 7 or later
        maxSize = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];

    }
    return maxSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` is deprecated in iOS7. 
You should use `sizeWithAttributes:` instead.

Example:

```
NSDictionary *fontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]};
CGSize textSize = [self.myLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:fontAttributes];
CGFloat textWidth = textSize.width;
CGFloat textHeight = textSize.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

I all the time use `sizeThatFits:`

```
CGRect frame = myLabel.frame;
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(myLabel.frame), 20000.0f);
CGSize size = [myLabel sizeThatFits:constraint];
frame.size.height = size.height;
myLabel.frame = frame;
```

You can try this

Answer (score 0):

Super simple. Just get the area of the text, divide by width, then round up to the nearest height that will fit your font.

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString*)text font:(UIFont*)font withinWidth:(CGFloat)width {
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
    CGFloat area = size.height * size.width;
    CGFloat height = roundf(area / width);
    return ceilf(height / font.lineHeight) * font.lineHeight;
}
```

Very much a plug and play solution. I use it in a helper class a lot, especially for dynamically sized UITableViewCells.

Hope this helps others in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I have a situation where i need to set the height of label dynamically according to text. I am using Xcode 7.1 and my project deployment target is 7.0 but i tested it on iOS 9 simulator and following solution works for me. Here is the solution:
First of of you will create a dictionary like this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:self.YOUR_LABEL.font};
```

now we will calculate the height and width for our text and pass the newly created dictionary.

```
    CGRect rect = [YOUR_TEXT_STRING boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:attributes
                                          context:nil];
```

Then we will set the frame of our LABEL:

```
    self.YOUR_LABEL.frame = CGRectMake(self.YOUR_LABEL.frame.origin.x, self.YOUR_LABEL.frame.origin.y, self.YOUR_LABEL.frame.size.width, rect.size.height);
```

THIS IS HOW I SUCCESSFULLY SET THE FRAME OF MY LABEL ACCORDING TO TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

This method is used and tested by me from iOS 7 to iOS 11.4

```
+ (CGFloat)getLabelHeight:(UILabel*)label
{
    NSParameterAssert(label);
    CGSize limitLabel = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize size;

    NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    CGSize labelBox = [label.text boundingRectWithSize: limitLabel
                                                  options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName:label.font }
                                                  context: context].size;

    size = CGSizeMake(ceil(labelBox.width), ceil(labelBox.height));
    return size.height;
}
```

So you can use like this:

```
CGFloat sizeOfFontTest = 12.0;
    UILabel *testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 0)];
    [testLabel setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: sizeOfFontTest]];
    [testLabel setText: @"Hello Stackoverflow Large String Example"];

    CGFloat heightTestLabel = [self getLabelHeight: testLabel];

    [testLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(testLabel.frame.origin.x, testLabel.frame.origin.y, testLabel.frame.size.width, heightAddrsLab)];
    [testLabel setNumberOfLines: sizeOfFontTest / heightTestLabel];
```

Answer (score -6):

this code is for moving four labels clockwise with the button tap, by using function for button:

```
(void)onclick
{
    CGRect newFrame;
    CGRect newFrame1 = lbl1.frame;
    CGRect newFrame2 = lbl2.frame;
    CGRect newFrame3 = lbl3.frame;
    CGRect newFrame4 = lbl4.frame;
    lbl1.frame=newFrame;
    lbl4.frame=newFrame1;
    lbl3.frame=newFrame4;
    lbl2.frame=newFrame3;
    lbl1.frame=newFrame2;
}
```