# fluid labels in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, label

I have 3 labels.

```
 _____
|_____| --> title
|_____| --> genre
|_____| --> subject
```

I am looking for when the title text is more than one line for the 2 labels below to move down.

Is this possible?

I have tried using this sort of thing

```
if (self.name.numberOfLines == 2) {
        NSLog(@"second line");
        [_genre setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 286, _genre.frame.size.width,
                                    _genre.frame.size.height)];
}
```

But this does not work. It does not even log. I have set the number of lines for the title to 0.

Is there any other way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numberOfLines` property doesn't change as the text gets bigger; you set it and the text wraps or truncates as appropriate.  My guess is it is 0 or 1 and not changing to 2 like you expect.

Instead what you need to do is figure out what text you want to display in the label, and then measure it.  You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20069229/74815) to get the height given a width constraint.

Once you know the required rect, set the first label's frame to be that size, then layout the next label as you do in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CGRectGetMaxY` to put your label directly under the other one :

```
[_genre setFrame:CGRectMake(20, CGRectGetMaxY(_title.frame), _genre.frame.size.width, _genre.frame.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboards? Are you using Auto Layout?
You have to set your constraints so that there is a spacing between the labels. Then set number of lines to 0.