# iOS how to set dynamic tableview cell height without autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, tableview

I am using custom tableview cell with three labels title,date and description, now I am getting data from web-services, in which some description text is too big to adjust within description label's frame

how to proceed with it ?

Answer (score 3):

simply use like

**ObjectiVe-C**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
...
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

**Swift**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {


        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```

**ObjectiVe-C**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 80; // customize the height
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

**Swift**

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return 80 // customize the height
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

finally set **your label.numofLines  =  0** in attribute or programtically

Comment: plz check my issue in below comment

Answer (score 3):

I would like to know why to know you're looking for a method without using autolayout. I believe previous posted answers are solutions using autolayout

## With Autolayout

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

and you can set [multiline label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/990244/6543229) to expand according to the content of the label

## Without Autolayout

Without autolayout you need to calculate height for each cell ([height for each labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27374612/6543229) + margins) individually and return the value in UITableView datasource method `- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 1):

write to `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: plz check my issue in below comment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but issue is not resolved
Please check images

1. Before without using above solutions My table view looks better but text is not adjusted
2. after using your help

[image]

using `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`
and `heightforcell` method everything is messed

My tableview with storyboard please check size inspector tab for autoresizing section

[image]

Whats the wrong am i doing here ?

Comment: you have to set line number of label to 0, do you use `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = current row height`
`