# Customized UITableViewCell Update Subviews

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a customized a `UITableviewCell`. There is a title label and a detail label inside.

Now I want to adjust the detail label attributes according to the content.
If the string size is greater than the frame then set the number of line to 2.

I have tried to put the code in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `layoutSubViews` in the cell class.

The piece of code is like

```
TransportationViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIFont* font = cell.detailLabel.font;
NSDictionary* attribute = @{NSFontAttributeName:font};
const CGSize textSize   = [cell.detailLabel.text sizeWithAttributes: attribute];

if (textSize.width > cell.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width && cell.detailLabel.numberOfLines == 1) {

    NSLog(@"%lf, %lf, %lu", cell.detailLabel.frame.size.width, textSize.width, (long)cell.detailLabel.numberOfLines);
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
}
```

It actually passed the if condition but the setting of label doesn't work.

Comment: probably you are confusing between detailLabel and detailTextLabel?
the second thing is that you do not need to call here '[cell setNeedsLayout]' it should work without this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write below code in view didload

```
self.theTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
self.theTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

[self.theTableView setNeedsLayout];
[self.theTableView layoutIfNeeded];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexpath     cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

Answer (score 0):

set `numberOfLines = 0;`

this will solve your problem.

Edit 1: code for calculating dynamic height.

```
 CGSize boundingBox = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                              context:context].size;
```

Thne on the basis of this height you can do the further calculations.

For more info, you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27374760/5660422

Comment: But I still need to dynamically setting the font size somewhere